# Passing arguments to this function which uses pvmismatch: Why is this not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pvlib

I am using a library called pvmismatch which measures the impact of imperfect shading on solar cells, which I think will soon be compatible with pvlib. I am not sure if this is a question related to python in general or just the library, but probably the former.

I would like to create a function which takes in a list of "shadings" which uses "setSuns" and also the indices of which cells are to be shaded. My code is below:

```
def shade_into_powers(shades_list = [], temperatures_list = [], cells_list = []):
    length_of_lists = len(shades_list)
    list_of_powers = []
    for i in range(0, length_of_lists):
        my_module_shaded.setSuns(Ee = shades_list[i], cells = cells_list[i])
        my_module_shaded.setTemps(Tc=temperatures_list[i], cells= cells_list[i])
        list_of_powers[i] = my_module_shaded.pvcells[i].Igen*max(my_module_shaded.pvcells[i].Vcell)
    return list_of_powers
```

I later tried to try out this function as below:

```
shadez = [0.43, 0.43, 0.43]
tempez = [88, 81, 77]
cellz = [30, 31, 32]
powers_listed = shade_into_powers(shadez, tempez, cellz)
```

The error I get is "object of type 'int' is not iterable". What am I doing wrong here?

All help appreciated.

The below is the TraceBack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abed/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.2/scratches/scratch_2.py", line 176, in <module>
    powers_listed = shade_into_powers(shadez, tempez, cellz)
  File "/home/abed/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.2/scratches/scratch_2.py", line 168, in shade_into_powers
    my_module_shaded.setSuns(Ee = shades_list[i], cells = cells_list[i])
  File "/home/abed/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pvmismatch/pvmismatch_lib/pvmodule.py", line 323, in setSuns
    cells_to_update = [self.pvcells[i] for i in cells]
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: What is the exact error with trace?

Comment: Also note, having lists as default arguments (`shades_list = []`) is a usually [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

Comment: Thank you @Carcigenicate. I have added the TraceBack. I have no choice, really, but to use lists in this case.

Comment: You can use lists, but make the default argument `None`, then assign the list inside the function if it's `None`. And unfortunately that error appears to be library specific, so I can't help much. Definitely fix the default argument though. That *will* bite you at some point (it bites everyone at some point). See the link on a better description of the fix I mentioned.

Comment: From looking at the error again, `cells= cells_list[i]` in the calls to `setSuns` and `setTemps` should be `cells= cells_list`. Note the parameter is "cells" (plural), not "cell"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for using [PVmismatch](https://sunpower.github.io/PVMismatch). As [@carcigenicate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3000206/carcigenicate), says in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64216311/passing-arguments-to-this-function-which-uses-pvmismatch-why-is-this-not-workin#comment113573745_64216311), the reason you are getting `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` is because the expected argument for `cells` in `setSuns()` is a *list* as documented in the [API](https://sunpower.github.io/PVMismatch/api/pvmodule.html#pvmismatch.pvmismatch_lib.pvmodule.PVmodule.setSuns):
[image]

I think you are trying to set the irradiance & temperature for 3 cells in a module. If correct, you can do this in a single call to `setSuns` followed by a single call to `setTemps`. Also note that [cell temperatures are Kelvin](https://sunpower.github.io/PVMismatch/api/pvmodule.html#pvmismatch.pvmismatch_lib.pvmodule.PVmodule.setTemps), not Celsius. Also note you can get the max cell temperatures by calling the NumPy `max()` function on the array of IV-curve powers, `Pcell[cell_idx]`.

```py
>>> from pvmismatch import *

>>> shadez = [0.43, 0.43, 0.43]
>>> tempez = [88, 81, 77]
>>> cellz = [30, 31, 32]

>>> my_module_shaded = pvmodule.PVmodule()

>>> my_module_shaded.Pmod.max()  # module max power
321.2733629193704

# power of cells 30, 31, & 32, same for all cells in module
>>> [cellpower.max() for cellpower in my_module_shaded.Pcell[cellz]]
[3.3466338806725577, 3.3466338806725577, 3.3466338806725577]

>>> my_module_shaded.setSuns(Ee=shadez, cells=cellz)

>>> my_module_shaded.Pmod.max()  # module max power, after irradiance change
217.32753929640674

# NOTE: cell temperature is in Kelvin, not Celsius!
>>> tempez = [tc + 273.15 for tc in tempez]  # convert to Kelvin
>>> my_module_shaded.setTemps(Tc=tempez, cells=cellz)

>>> my_module_shaded.Pmod.max()  # module max power, after temperature change
215.93464636002747

# power of cells 30, 31, & 32, same for all cells in module
>>> [cellpower.max() for cellpower in my_module_shaded.Pcell[cellz]]
[1.0892289330819398, 1.1230533440517434, 1.1424662134689452]
```

Answer (score 0):

List of powers is an empty array. Try replacing `list_of_powers[i] = my_module_shaded.pvcells[i].Igen*max(my_module_shaded.pvcells[i].Vcell)` with `list_of_powers.append(my_module_shaded.pvcells[i].Igen*max(my_module_shaded.pvcells[i].Vcell))`

Comment: That may be true, but that won't lead to the error that they mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately this does not solve the problem.